# Does rounding values speed up JSON communication (ajax)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

since I want to receive a lot of data multiple times per second with an $ajax (or jQuery.getJSON) method, I wonder if it could make sense to round long float values (1.23242342344 ... ) to a short version.

As far as I know it doesn't make a difference in most programming languages if its 2.2 or 2.202312323, since both reserve the space of a float, but I'm not sure how JSON handles this, maybe it's more like a string, and the string would get shorter with rounded values?

So, can I speed up JSON calls with rounded values?

Comment: You'd just be saving a couple of bytes per float, for most applications, this is completely insignificant. look for optimizations elsewhere :o

Comment: Yes, it will make the Json String shorter and faster, But you will observe this improvement only when there would be ALOT of data.

Comment: Yes, the JSON string will be a bit shorter. Worth it? Hard to tell, probably not. How many bytes can you shave off your payload compared to constant HTTP overhead and network latency?

Comment: could you give some context on why you need to make so many ajax requests a second..

Comment: Wow, thanks for the many replies. I have no clue what is "a lot" of data and what not, but I can tell you what I want to do: I want to draw a graph with around 10 lines (could be more or less), each containing around 1k points.
  
The user should now be able to change a parameter through a slider, and the plot should update accordingly - therefore the data should update as much as possible (maybe around 30 times a second).

Comment: i would interpret this as all of this logic can be happening in javascript on the client - no need to spam the server with ajax requests, until some sort of save events actually need to invoke the server functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rounding values will make a difference, proportional to the amount of data you transfer.

All HTTP communication is done with Strings and JSON is a string format to transfer data.
Therefore 12.3456789 will take 10 bytes where as 12 will only need 2 (one byte per character).

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted to know. If it really matters for my use case (in the comments) is of course a different question - do you have any Idea about this? E.g. on what amount of data this might be relevant?

Comment: I cannot guess your exact requirements. But as a back-of-the-envelope calculation: if you have 10 lines with 1K points each this is 10K numbers per request. Assuming 2 digits before dot and 6 decimals on average, not-rounded will be 90K numbers per request, or 2.7MB per second (too much). If you round to no decimals, you get down to 0.6MB per seconds (78% down but still too much). On top of that you need to add the overhead of the JSON format and HTTP, but this is the same no matter if you round or not.

Comment: Thank you, that is impressive - and a strong improvement, even more so, that I just saved my json data and it is around 140KB per one single request without rounding. And this with only 6k points (length of one point: 0.38863413810902986).

So rounding may definitely help, and since (for now) I only want to use it for intranet (or mostly on the same computer), 0.6MB per second might be ok. Transfering to the web I guess the best way is to cut down the points.